# proving that an improper integral diverges

Tags: calculus, integration

I was wondering if I could get a hint on checking the convergence of the following integral: $$\int_1^\infty x^a\sin^3x \, dx $$
For a>0 I don't know how to show it diverges(or converges). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**just for nonexistence of the limit**

Let $f (x)=x^a\sin^3 (x), $

$$u_n=\frac {\pi}{2}+2n\pi $$
and
$$v_n=n\pi $$

then

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f (u_n)=+\infty $$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f (v_n)=0$$

thus
$\lim_{x\to+\infty}f (x) $ does not exist.

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty} sin(x^2)$ converges yet the limit of the function does not exist, like in the case I posted. Or is it a different case?

Comment: @Eliads If the limit exists, it should be zero. If the limit exists and is not zero, the integral diverges.

Comment: I understand that, thank you. But in the case you posted the limit does not exist.

Comment: @Eliads It was just how to prove the limit does not exist.

Comment: $$\int_{1}^{+\infty}x^a \sin^3(x)\,dx $$
is conditionally convergent for any $a<0$ by Dirichlet's test and absolutely convergent for any $a<-1$.